# Is it possible to change the structure of the HTML generated by the_content()? If yes, how? If not, is there a workaround?

Tags: customization, the-content

Suppose the editor on my admin dashboard creates the following HTML (when I print to the webpage using `the_content()`:

```
<blockquote>Hello this is the best quote in the world!</blockquote>
<blockquote>Hello this is the second best quote in the world!</blockquote>
<blockquote>Hello this is the third best quote in the world!</blockquote>
<h2>This is a heading for a paragraph</h2>
<p>This is some paragraph.</p>
.
.
.
```

From this, I want to group together the quotes in a `div` and group the rest of the content of the page in a separate `div`. Something like this:

```
<div class="my-blockquotes">
    <blockquote>Hello this is the best quote in the world!</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Hello this is the second best quote in the world!</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Hello this is the third best quote in the world!</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="main-content">
    <h2>This is a heading for a paragraph</h2>
    <p>This is some paragraph.</p>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

**Basically, is there a way to change the structure of the HTML that `the_content()` generates?** I tried searching about walker classes, but that's not available for `the_content()`. I tried hacky fixes like using shortcodes, but could not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks), to literally filter the content into your structure.

Somthing like this

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content',function($the_content){
    // find blockquotes
    $regex = '/<blockquote>(.+?)<\/blockquote>([\n|$])/i';
    $blockquotes = preg_match_all($regex,$the_content,$matches);

    // remove blockquotes
    $main_content = preg_replace($regex,'',$the_content);

    // rebuild blockqoutes
    $my_blockquotes = '';
    foreach ($matches[1] as $blockquote) {
        $my_blockquotes .= "<blockquote>{$blockquote}</blockquote>";
    }

    // rebuild content
    $new_content = '';
    if (!empty($my_blockquotes)) {
        $new_content = "
        <div class='my-blockquotes'>
            {$my_blockquotes}
        </div>\n";
    }
    $new_content .= "
    <div class='main-content'>
        {$main_content}
    </div>\n";

    return $new_content;
});
```

but you'll notice this still might feel a little *hacky* as you're separating user-supplied content where unexpected user error can still happen. For example: line-breaks may be inconsistent between blockquotes.

You'd be better off creating [a custom metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) and/or using [post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to store these blockquotes individually, as meta data to the post. You can then throw them in before your content (with out parsing with regex) via `the_content` still, or you can edit your template files of your theme, or hook into another action in your theme.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Is there a convention about when one should use custom metabox or post_meta?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar - in my case, I was applying a class directly on any `blockquote` tags using string replace.

```
<?php
$content = the_content();
$content = str_replace( "<blockquote>", "<blockquote class=\"quote\">", $content );
echo $content;
?>
```

Read more about string replace here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Came to this answer in my search to "rewrite" blockquotes in the_content and this in turn led me to a different solution using php domdocument functions which I'll post below for any possible help it may provide.

```
/**
 * Add tweet link to blockquotes
 */
function my_blockquote_tweets( $the_content ) {

    global $wp;

    // Parse content
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML( $the_content );
    $blockquotes = $document->getElementsByTagName('blockquote');

    $svg = file_get_contents( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/resources/images/svg/social-logos/twitter.svg' );

    foreach ($blockquotes as $blockquote) {

        // Twitter Icon
        $twitter_svg = $document->createDocumentFragment();
        $twitter_svg->appendXML( $svg );

        // Icon wrapper
        $twitter_logo_wrapper = $document->createElement('span');
        $twitter_logo_wrapper->setAttribute('class', 'tweet-logo');
        $twitter_logo_wrapper->appendChild( $twitter_svg );

        $tweet_text = substr($blockquote->nodeValue, 0, 250);

        if( strlen( $tweet_text ) > 250 ) {
            $tweet_text .= ' &#8230;';
        }

        $tweet = $document->createElement('a');
        $tweet->setAttribute( 'class', 'tweet-this group' );
        $tweet->setAttribute( 'title', __('Tweet this quote', 'pwa') );
        $tweet->setAttribute( 'href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' . urlencode( $tweet_text ) . '&url=%0A' . urlencode(home_url( $wp->request )));
        $tweet->setAttribute( 'target', '_blank' );

        $tweet->appendChild( $twitter_logo_wrapper );

        $tweet_text = $document->createTextNode( __( 'Tweet this' , 'pwa' ) );
        $tweet->appendChild( $tweet_text );

        $blockquote->appendChild( $tweet );

    }

    $the_content = $document->saveHtml();

    return $the_content;


}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_blockquote_tweets', 10, 1);
```

Hope it help someone.